# ServiceStack.Text JsonSerializer cannot deserialize its own serialized schema (Type definitions should start with a '{' SerializationException)

Tags: .net, serialization, servicestack, jsonserializer, servicestack-text

I am using ServiceStack.Text in .NET.
I want to serialize an instance of:

```
IDictionary<string, ResourceSpec>
```

ResourceSpec is:

```
public class ResourceSpec
{
    public string TypeName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public HashSet<Property> Properties
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

It serializes into this format:

```
{1:{"TypeName":"channel","Properties":[audio,video]},2:{"TypeName":"channel","Properties":[audio,video,encrypted]}}
```

When I try to deserialize it with:

```
JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromStream<IDictionary<string, ResourceSpec>>(file);
```

I get exception:

```
SerializationException: "Type definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type 'ResourceSpec', got string starting with: Properties"
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your serialized string seems to be missing some double quotes such as "1" and "audio", "video", etc. The quoted string deserialized fine for me using 3.9.71.